# Have all elements on page stick to a certain position once the the screen becomes a certain width and height (to prevent overlap)?

Tags: html, css

I need some help with preventing some elements on my page from overlapping once the screen size reduces to a certain width and height. There aren't very many items on my page (I'll provide the link to the repo below).

I setting up media queries for when the screen was a certain width and height and tried fixing the elements in place. However, this did not work. Is there an easy solution to this?

this is a link to the repository on Github: [gSchool Trivia](https://github.com/omaracrystal/gSchool_Trivia)
The best view is when the screen is at a min-width: 697 and min-height: 744... I would like all the items on the page to stick to these positions if the screen is reduced any smaller. I have photos of the app on github as well...

Comment: Your link does not seem to work, but have you tried media queries?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Thanks I have updated the link! I have tried media queries but it didn't seem to do anything :(

Comment: Couldn't you just add a `min-width` CSS property to the `body` or whatever container?

Comment: I just updated the link and I did have a min-width and min-height for the body - but this didn't seem to do much. I am now trying to solve this with creating div wrappers for each group of items and make the objects within those divs relative to that wrappers position.